# Emulator getting killed always : Emulator: Pixel 6a API 34 - Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, haxm

My android studio emulator is always getting killed whenever i run it .
Emulator: Pixel 6a API 34 - Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

**My log file from location C:\Users\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3\log**

```java
2023-10-16 00:41:09,480 [37581554]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6a API 34 - C:\Users\rk150\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_6a_API_34 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2023-10-16 00:41:09,534 [37581608]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6a API 34 - Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
2023-10-16 00:41:09,534 [37581608]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6a API 34 - Found systemPath C:\Users\rk150\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
2023-10-16 00:41:09,847 [37581921]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6a API 34 - Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): SupportPixelFold
2023-10-16 00:41:10,877 [37582951]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6a API 34 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\rk150\.android\avd\Pixel_6a_API_34.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2023-10-16 00:41:11,895 [37583969]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker - Error retrieving list of excluded patterns: Error code 5: Access is denied.
2023-10-16 00:41:11,895 [37583969]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.diagnostics.WindowsPerformanceHintsChecker - Windows Defender status: UNKNOWN_STATUS; projectDirExcluded? false
2023-10-16 00:41:11,897 [37583971]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jbr
2023-10-16 00:41:11,904 [37583978]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Couldn't get post build models.
2023-10-16 00:41:11,904 [37583978]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Gradle invocation complete, build result = com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.AssembleInvocationResult@143cf232
2023-10-16 00:41:11,915 [37583989]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Gradle build finished in 2 s 700 ms
2023-10-16 00:41:11,926 [37584000]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jbr
2023-10-16 00:41:14,980 [37587054]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6a API 34 - Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
2023-10-16 00:41:15,530 [37587604]   INFO - #c.i.e.r.ExecutionUtil - Error running 'app':<br>The emulator process for AVD Pixel_6a_API_34 has terminated.
java.lang.RuntimeException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_6a_API_34 has terminated.
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:246)
```

[image: error ss]

i have tried almost everything but nothing worked

- Reinstall android studio after clearing everything
- Created device again
- also have enough space in c drive approx 10 gb

EDIT inSDK tools i was trying to install HAXM accelerator but failed with the following error
Unable to install Intel® HAXM
HAXM requires an Intel CPU.
Please file a bug against Android Studio.

Comment: Try changing installation location on studio + sdk + emulator and run as administrator. The error seems like access error on protected folder.